# AWK script for search in a fasta file

Tags: bash, awk, fasta

I have such a fasta file :

```
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8571.2 FIHSSUW01ASCWS.2 length=224
GAGATGAAATAGATCTTGGCATATATGTACATGCTTGATCTCAGTTTTGATTGGATTTTATCCATTTTAG
CTATCTTAACTATTAATCTTGAAATGAAGCTTTAATTTATGTAGGAAGTTTATGAAATTTAGGAAAAAAA
AAGAAAAAAACAAAACAATGTCGGCCGCCTCGGTCTCTACTGAGACACGCAACAGGGGATAGGCAAGGCA
CACAGGGGATAGGN
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8572.2 FIHSSUW01ETZME.2 length=254
ACTAACCAGGTGGTAAACAACTACTACAGGCCAGATTTGAAGAAGGCTGCTCTTGCTAGATTGAGTGCAG
TGAACAGAAGCCTTAAGGTTTCAAAGTCTGGTGTGAAGAAGAAGAACAGACAGGCAGTTAGGATCCATGG
TAGGAAGTGAAGCTGTGATTTGCCTACCGTCTGATATTCATCGTATCACTTTCTAGCTGTTCCGTCTTGT
TTGGCAAGTGTTTGGTTTTACGTGCGAGTAGTTATATGTTGCGC
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8573.2 FIHSSUW01AZA99.2 length=230
AAGCAGTGGTATCAACGCAGAGTGGCCATTACGGCCGGGGATGTACCAATTCAAAAAGAAAACAGCAGTT
GGGGGCAAAACAATTAAGTTGTAACGAATGCATATATATGATTAATCTTCTAACACATTATTTTTGTCTC
AAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAAACAAAACATGTCGGCCGCCTCGGTCTCTACTGAGACACGCAACAGGGGATAGG
CAAGGCACACAGGGGATAGG
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8574.2 FIHSSUW01EHI3P.2 length=153
TGCAAGTTTACAACTTAAAACAACTTTTCTCACAGTGAACAATAAATTTATCAATTCTCATGCAAAAAAA
AAGAAAAAAACAAAAACATGTCGGCCGCCTCGGTCTCTACTGAGACACGCAACAGGGGATAGGCAAGGCA
CACAGGGGATAGG
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8575.2 FIHSSUW01EWK4S.2 length=287
AACAGTGGTATCAACGCAGAGTGGCCATTACGGCCGGGAGATTACAGGTATTGCAAGTTTCAAGCCTGTC
ATAAAGACTCAAAGCCGCTTGTAATTTGTGTTTCCTAGTTGGGGAAGCTGTTTGTTCTTTATTGTGCTAT
ATGTATTTATTTGAAAGTTTGGATGAACTCAATAAATAAAAGAAAATCTTCATTGTGGGTTACAATTTGG
ACATGAACATGCATGAATAATGTACCAATTTAGCAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAACAAAAAACAAATAGTCGGC
CGGCCCG
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8576.2 FIHSSUW01C911A.2 length=265
TATTCTCAGGTACGAAATATGAGTTTGCTGATAAATTGATGGATTGGGAATCAGCCTGCATAATAAGATA
TTCCCAATTAACTTTGCCCGTTAGTTCTTTTAGCTTTTCCTTTAAAGGCACGAGTCTTTCAACCAAAACA
TTACAGCAAAGTCTAACTGCCTCACAGCTTGCTTCAGAAGTTGTACCCCCGGCCGTAATGGCCACTCTGC
GTTGATACCACTGCTTCTGAGACACGCAACAGGGGATAGGCAAGGCACACAGGGG
```

and i have wrote this script in bash

```
STRING=$1
FILE=$(pwd)"/"$2

if [ -z "$STRING" ] 
then 
    echo "Usage: fastaFind.sh <query> <fasta file>"
else
    echo ""
    awk  'BEGIN { RS = ">" } ; $0 ~ "'$STRING'" { print $0 }' "$FILE"
fi
```

I am running this command

```
 fastaFind.sh "gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8573.2 FIHSSUW01AZA99.2 length=230" file.fasta
```

but it returns me an error for unterminated string. What i want to achieve is to retrieve after the execution of the command the specific sequence of the query. e.g

```
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8573.2 FIHSSUW01AZA99.2 length=230
AAGCAGTGGTATCAACGCAGAGTGGCCATTACGGCCGGGGATGTACCAATTCAAAAAGAAAACAGCAGTT
GGGGGCAAAACAATTAAGTTGTAACGAATGCATATATATGATTAATCTTCTAACACATTATTTTTGTCTC
AAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAAACAAAACATGTCGGCCGCCTCGGTCTCTACTGAGACACGCAACAGGGGATAGG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `awk` command would better be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS = ""; RS = ">"; FS="\n" } $1 == "pattern" { print ">" $0 }' file
```

Or

```
awk -v p="pattern" 'BEGIN {ORS = ""; RS = ">"; FS = "\n" } $1 == p { print ">" $0 }' file
```

And your shell script be:

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING=$1
FILE=$2

if [[ -z $STRING ]]; then
    echo "Usage: fastaFind.sh <query> <fasta file>"
else
    awk -v p="$STRING" 'BEGIN{ ORS=""; RS=">"; FS="\n" } $1 == p { print ">" $0 }' "$FILE"
fi
```

Example usage:

```
bash temp.sh 'gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8575.2 FIHSSUW01EWK4S.2 length=287' temp.txt
```

Output:

```
>gnl|SRA|SRR035294.8575.2 FIHSSUW01EWK4S.2 length=287
AACAGTGGTATCAACGCAGAGTGGCCATTACGGCCGGGAGATTACAGGTATTGCAAGTTTCAAGCCTGTC
ATAAAGACTCAAAGCCGCTTGTAATTTGTGTTTCCTAGTTGGGGAAGCTGTTTGTTCTTTATTGTGCTAT
ATGTATTTATTTGAAAGTTTGGATGAACTCAATAAATAAAAGAAAATCTTCATTGTGGGTTACAATTTGG
ACATGAACATGCATGAATAATGTACCAATTTAGCAAAAAAAAAGAAAAAAACAAAAAACAAATAGTCGGC
CGGCCCG
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues to be settled.

1. Quoting is wrong.  Since you're evaluating the shell's `STRING` variable inside the call to `awk`, the whole `awk` command must be enclosed in double quotes.  But then you have to escape double quotes *inside* the `awk` command.
2. The matching operator `~` cannot be used, since the pattern contains characters (like `|`) that have a special meaning inside regular expressions.  Hence you need a method to match just a portion of the input *record*; this is the reason behind the comparison on `$1` (made possible by redefining `FS`).

.

```
STRING=$1
FILE=$(pwd)"/"$2

if [ -z "$STRING" ]
then
    echo "Usage: fastaFind.sh <query> <fasta file>"
else
    echo ""
    awk  "BEGIN { RS = \">\" ; FS = \"\n\" } ; \$1 == \"$STRING\" { print \$0 }" "$FILE"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just something like that:

```sh
awk -v "RS=>" '/length=254/ { print $0; }' file
```